# Problema con requests de Python

Tags: python, xampp, python-requests

Tengo un servidor XAMPP en Windows, del cual quiero descargarme desde otro terminal un fichero pdf localizado en C:/xampp/htdocs/ usando la librería requests de Python y ponerlo en el directorio de Descargas
La dirección IP del servidor es 192.168.1.134 y el puerto es 8081.
Este es el código:

```
url="http://192.168.1.134:8081/c:/xampp/htdocs/informe.pdf"
response=requests.get(url)
tofile=open('/../Users/PABLO/Downloads/informelocal.pdf','wb')
tofile.write(response.content)
tofile.close()
```

El fichero se genera correctamente en Descargas, pero una vez que intento abrirlo, descubro que está corrupto y no se puede abrir. He probado con direcciones imaginarias y veo que ocurre lo mismo así que probablemente sea cosa de la URL, pero le he dado mil vueltas y no se cómo ponerlo bien.
¡Gracias por vuestro tiempo!

Comment: Cuando dices que está corrupto? ¿Es porque tiene caracteres aleatorios? ¿Has probado a abrirlo con el block de notas a ver si es que el servidor te ha devuelto un mensaje de error? ¿Qué error te está devolviendo?

Comment: Añadiendo a lo comentado por eferion, es posible que la conexión se estableciera correctamente con el servidor pero que este no te responda con el archivo por cualquier causa: ¿que te muestra `response.status_code`? Alternativamente puedes intentar que se lance una excepción con `response.raise_for_status()`. Muestra lo que te sale en cualquier caso, porque puede que estés escribiendo el resultado de una respuesta 404 o vete a saber....

Answer (score 0):

Por si el problema estuviese en la conexión, ¿has probado a utilizar una conexión con sesión?

```
session = requests.Session()
session.trust_env = False
r = session.get(link)
pdf = r.content
with open(file, 'wb') as f:
  f.write(pdf)
```

¿O si lo originase el tamaño del fichero, una descarga a trozos? (https://likegeeks.com/es/descargar-archivos-usando-python/)

```
r = requests.get(url, stream = True)
with open(file, "wb") as Pypdf:
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size = 1024):
        if chunk:
            Pypdf.write(chunk)
```

Si ninguna de estas dos opciones te funciona, por favor añade más información sobre tu situación. Por ejemplo, podría ser interesante saber si el fichero que se genera en descargas pesa igual que el fichero original, o la versión de Python que estas utilizando.

Gracias!